# No such image: my-image:latest while pushing container with Github Actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am modifying my `docker-publish` file to build a docker image so it can work with Arm64. The previous version was working fine with x86 architecture, but now I need to make it work for Arm 64 so I just changed the way the docker builds the images.

The build process works fine but somehow the git push stopped working and I am getting the error

```
Error response from daemon: No such image: myimage-arm64:latest
```

This is my `docker-publish.yml`

```
name: Docker

on:
  push:
    # Publish `master` as Docker `latest` image.
    branches:
      - master

    # Publish `v1.2.3` tags as releases.
    tags:
      - v*

  # Run tests for any PRs.
  pull_request:

env:
  IMAGE_NAME: myimage-arm64

jobs:
  # Push image to GitHub Packages.
  # See also https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/
  push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event_name == 'push'

    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
        
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        id: buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      
      - name: Prepare multiarch docker
        run: docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
      
      - name: Builder create
        run: docker buildx create --use
      
      - name: Log into registry
        run: echo "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" | docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin

      - name: Build image
        run: |
          docker buildx build \
            --tag $IMAGE_NAME \
            --file Dockerfile \
            --platform linux/arm64 .

      - name: Push image
        run: |
          IMAGE_ID=docker.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository }}/$IMAGE_NAME

          # Change all uppercase to lowercase
          IMAGE_ID=$(echo $IMAGE_ID | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')

          # Strip git ref prefix from version
          # VERSION=$(echo "${{ github.ref }}" | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
          # I changed this so it takes the version from a file on my project
          VERSION=$(cat version)

          # Strip "v" prefix from tag name
          [[ "${{ github.ref }}" == "refs/tags/"* ]] && VERSION=$(echo $VERSION | sed -e 's/^v//')

          # Use Docker `latest` tag convention
          [ "$VERSION" == "master" ] && VERSION=latest

          echo IMAGE_ID=$IMAGE_ID
          echo VERSION=$VERSION

          ###
          The two previous echo print the correct stuff
          I get the error in these last two lines
          ###
          docker tag $IMAGE_NAME $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION
          docker push $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION
```

Any help? The push phase was working fine previously and I haven't touched it to make it work with arm64

EDIT 1:

I modified the procedure following the answers but still it does not work (error: tag is needed when pushing to register)

```
 - name: Log into registry
    run: echo "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" | docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin
  
  - name: Builder create
    run: docker buildx create --use      

  - name: Build image
    run: |
      IMAGE_ID=docker.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository }}/$IMAGE_NAME
      VERSION=$(cat version)
      echo TAG=$IMAGE_ID:$VERSION
      docker buildx build --push \            
        --tag $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION  \
        --file Dockerfile \
        --platform linux/arm64 .
```

Precisely, the logs are these ones:

```
Run IMAGE_ID=docker.pkg.github.com/GiamBoscaro/portfolio-website/$IMAGE_NAME
TAG=docker.pkg.github.com/UserName/RepoName/ImageName:1.2.0
#1 [internal] booting buildkit
#1 sha256:bfa0dddd89a9c970aa189079c1d31d17f7a75edd434bb19ad90432b27b266e3a
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 0.4s done
#1 creating container buildx_buildkit_intelligent_volhard0
#1 creating container buildx_buildkit_intelligent_volhard0 0.9s done
#1 DONE 1.3s
error: tag is needed when pushing to registry
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

EDIT 2: Finally fixed the issue. Even if it's not the best way, here's the code that works. I switched over to the new container registry and moved the docker login in the same job of docker buildx:

```
jobs:
  push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event_name == 'push'

    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
        
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        id: buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      
      - name: Prepare multiarch docker
        run: docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
      
      - name: Builder create
        run: docker buildx create --use      

      - name: Build image
        run: |
          IMAGE_ID=ghcr.io/${{ github.actor }}/$IMAGE_NAME

          # Change all uppercase to lowercase
          IMAGE_ID=$(echo $IMAGE_ID | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')

          VERSION=$(cat version)
          
          echo TAG=$IMAGE_ID:$VERSION

          echo "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin

          docker buildx build --push \
            --tag $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION  \
            --file Dockerfile.arm \
            --platform linux/arm64 .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buildx runs builds within a separate container, not directly in your docker engine. And the output of buildx does not store the resulting image in the local docker engine. This doesn't work when you get into multi-platform images anyway, so you typically push directly to the registry. It's much more efficient to avoid moving layers around that didn't change in the registry, and allows you to manage multi-platform images (everything loaded into the docker engine is dereferenced to a single platform).

If you really want to save the output to the local docker engine, you can use `--load` in the buildx command. However, the preferred option is to use the [build-push-action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) that builds your tag directly and pushes it in one step. This would mean reordering your steps to determine the versions and other variables first, and then run the build against that. You can see [an example of this in my own project](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/blob/d115beedd5d3bcd62229b7b82a253377b4f05697/.github/workflows/docker.yml) which was assembled from various other docker examples out there.

Here's a quick untested attempt to make that change:

```
 - name: Prepare
   id: prep
   run: |
      IMAGE_ID=docker.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository }}/$IMAGE_NAME

      # Change all uppercase to lowercase
      IMAGE_ID=$(echo $IMAGE_ID | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')

      # Strip git ref prefix from version
      # VERSION=$(echo "${{ github.ref }}" | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
      # I changed this so it takes the version from a file on my project
      VERSION=$(cat version)

      # Strip "v" prefix from tag name
      [[ "${{ github.ref }}" == "refs/tags/"* ]] && VERSION=$(echo $VERSION | sed -e 's/^v//')

      # Use Docker `latest` tag convention
      [ "$VERSION" == "master" ] && VERSION=latest

      echo IMAGE_ID=$IMAGE_ID
      echo VERSION=$VERSION
      echo ::set-output name=version::${VERSION}
      echo ::set-output name=docker_tag::${IMAGE_ID}:${VERSION}

 - name: Build and push
   uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
   with:
     context: .
     file: Dockerfile
     platforms: linux/arm64
     push: true
     tags: ${{ steps.prep.outputs.docker_tag }}
```

---

From the updated question, this is the entire command being run:

```
docker buildx build --push
```

The next command to run would be:

```
--tag $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION ...
```

I'm sure you're saying "Wait, what? There's a trailing slash, that's a multi-line command!" But there's also whitespace after that slash, so instead of escaping a linefeed, you've escaped a space character. Docker treats that space as the one arg and will attempt to build with the context being a directory named  . To fix, remove the trailing whitespace after the backslash.

Comment: that makes sense! I don't care about saving the image or whatever, if it's better to direcly push with buildx I am ok with that. I'll try your code asap, thank you!

Comment: I get now this: error: tag is needed when pushing to registry
I modified my script following your guidelines to build and push:

      - name: Build and push image
        run: |
          IMAGE_ID=docker.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository }}/$IMAGE_NAME
          VERSION=$(cat version)
          echo TAG=$IMAGE_ID:$VERSION
          
          docker buildx build --push \            
            --tag $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION  \
            --file Dockerfile \
            --platform linux/arm64 .

Comment: @gbos comments are difficult to read with code, please update the question with your current attempt and error message.

Comment: yes sorry, I updated the answer. But I figured that you use @v2 for buildx and you use context to add all tags etc. I am wondering if my way is wrong or if they're equivalent

Comment: @gbos I'm not sure what you mean by "does not work". Please include the error message, or commands that don't have the expected result, allowing how it does not work.

Comment: error: tag is needed when pushing to registr

Comment: @gbos your previous line had an echo of the tag, what did that show? Include enough output in the question so we can follow, we don't have access to your environment to see what's happening so we need context around your question.

Comment: ehy sorry for the late response. I was at work and I am not that good at multitasking. anyway the echo worked correctly, it printed out the correct tag. I updated the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232528/discussion-between-bmitch-and-gbos).